# How can I add banners after categories in main page in Phpbb?

Tags: php, ads, banner, phpbb, phpbb3

How can I add banners after categories in main page in Phpbb? 
[image: like this photo]

I tried in forumlist_body.html, viewforum_body.html and viewtopic_body.html. But I never see a difference. I use phpbb 3.1.
[image: my style page in admin panel] its my style in admin panel. I used DVGFX theme but it inheritanced from prosilver.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure about 3.1, but in older versions of phpBB you must clear the style cache in the ACP before you will see any changes.

Comment: I tried clear but no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file to change is [forumlist_body.html](https://github.com/phpbb/phpbb/blob/release-3.1.10/phpBB/styles/prosilver/template/forumlist_body.html)

Here are the original lines 11 to 27

```
<!-- IF forumrow.S_IS_CAT or forumrow.S_FIRST_ROW  or forumrow.S_NO_CAT  -->
    <div class="forabg">
        <div class="inner">
        <ul class="topiclist">
            <li class="header">
                <!-- EVENT forumlist_body_category_header_row_prepend -->
                <dl class="icon">
                    <dt><div class="list-inner"><!-- IF forumrow.S_IS_CAT --><a href="{forumrow.U_VIEWFORUM}">{forumrow.FORUM_NAME}</a><!-- ELSE -->{L_FORUM}<!-- ENDIF --></div></dt>
                    <dd class="topics">{L_TOPICS}</dd>
                    <dd class="posts">{L_POSTS}</dd>
                    <dd class="lastpost"><span>{L_LAST_POST}</span></dd>
                </dl>
                <!-- EVENT forumlist_body_category_header_row_append -->
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="topiclist forums">
<!-- ENDIF -->
```

You have to prepend something like this :

```
<!-- IF forumrow.S_IS_CAT -->
    add your ADS here
<!-- ENDIF -->
```

But the best way is to overload the `forumlist_body_category_header_before` event. So your code should be :

```
<!-- IF forumrow.S_IS_CAT -->
    <a href="site2.com">
        <img alt="" height="80" src="site1.com/reklam/ads.jpg"; width="1000">
    </a> 
<!-- ENDIF -->
<!-- IF forumrow.S_IS_CAT or forumrow.S_FIRST_ROW  or forumrow.S_NO_CAT  -->
    <div class="forabg">
        <div class="inner">
        <ul class="topiclist">
            <li class="header">
                <!-- EVENT forumlist_body_category_header_row_prepend -->
                <dl class="icon">
                    <dt><div class="list-inner"><!-- IF forumrow.S_IS_CAT --><a href="{forumrow.U_VIEWFORUM}">{forumrow.FORUM_NAME}</a><!-- ELSE -->{L_FORUM}<!-- ENDIF --></div></dt>
                    <dd class="topics">{L_TOPICS}</dd>
                    <dd class="posts">{L_POSTS}</dd>
                    <dd class="lastpost"><span>{L_LAST_POST}</span></dd>
                </dl>
                <!-- EVENT forumlist_body_category_header_row_append -->
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="topiclist forums">
<!-- ENDIF -->
```

This tips will help you during dev : Check that in `PCA` > `General` > `Server configuration` > `Load Settings` > `General options` > `Recompile stale style components` is set to **Yes** . So you don't have to reload cache after each update

Comment: Did you have removed bracket each side of `add your ADS` here ? Did your clear cache ? Did you change settings to detect each style modification and calculated them ?

Comment: <dl class="icon">
      <dt><div class="list-inner"><!-- IF forumrow.S_IS_CAT --><a href="http://www.site2.com"><img alt="" height="80" src="http://www.site1.com/reklam/ads.jpg" width="1000"></a> <a href="{forumrow.U_VIEWFORUM}">{forumrow.FORUM_NAME}</a><!-- ELSE -->{L_FORUM}<!-- ENDIF --></div></dt>
      <dd class="topics">{L_TOPICS}</dd>

its my code. <a href="http://www.site2.com"><img alt="" height="80" src="http://www.site1.com/reklam/ads.jpg" width="1000"></a>   for ads.

Comment: I edited my answer. Don't forget to clean cache. And please could you be a little more explicit ? What do you mean by "it didn't work" ?

Comment: I did but no changes. I'm new in phpbb. I did this change in my styles/themename/template/forumlist_body.html. But i never see a change.

Comment: I edited my main question. My style DVGFX but it inheritanced prosilver. I made changes to two themes. But cant see a change.

Comment: Setting the new style as default will not change the existing style for you or other existing members. Check in your owwn user profile that your are using this DVGFX style too.

Comment: I checked it. I use DVGFX style but also i made all changes in two themes.

Comment: I tried to delete forumlist_body.html but site didnt down. Is it normal ?

Comment: no ! It is not normal. If site is still working, it is because of misconfiguration. You're not using this theme.

Comment: It is work because inheritanced from prosilver. I deleted two forumlist_body and site down. But my problem never solved.

Comment: This tips will help you during dev : Check that in PCA > General > Server configuration > Load Settings > General options > Recompile stale style components: is set to `Yes` . So you don't have to reload cache after each update.

Comment: It's work!!! Thanks so much. But i reload cache after all update. I dont understand how its work :)

Comment: Generating style is heavy. So there is a cache system to provide good performances. You could reload cache manually after each modification, or you could modify this option. (But I think you should reload cache the first time you changed this option.

Comment: Okey. I understand it. Thanks i cant solve without you :)